# Using AdMob Adverts with ListAdapter on Android

Tags: android, admob

I am currently developing an app where the main screen hasn't got an actual view as in setContentView(R.layout.myScreen); is used. Instead it uses an XML file which just details a textview which is assigned to an list adapter and fill with data from the database.

Below is the XML file that is used

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.BoardiesITSolutions.PasswordManager"
            android:id="@+id/showLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp">
    </TextView>
```

And below is the code where data is added to the textview list adapter

public class ShowLogins extends ListActivity {

```
String LOGINS[] = null;
String company = null;
String longClickCompany;

String companyName = "";
String companyURL = "";
String companyUsername = "";
String companyPassword = "";
Boolean passwordEnabled;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);

    boolean enablePassword = settings.getBoolean("enablePassword", false);
    boolean loggedIn = settings.getBoolean("loggedIn", false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (loggedIn)
    {
        passwordEnabled = settings.getBoolean("enablePassword", false);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_login);

    //registerForContextMenu(getListView());


    addToArray();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.showLoginBox, LOGINS));

    //ListView lv = getListView();
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.show_list_view);
    //View myView = findViewById(R.layout.advert);
    //lv.addView(myView);

    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            longClickCompany = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            return false;
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            company = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(company, "\n");
            String companyName = st.nextToken();
            String username = st.nextToken();
            prepareLoadingWebsite(companyName, username);
        }
    });
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowLogins.this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void addToArray()
{
    int totalRows = 0;
    int added = 0;
    int arrayField = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    Cursor c = null;
    Cursor count = null;
    try
    {
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        count = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PASSWORD", null);
        if (count.moveToNext())
        {
            totalRows = count.getInt(0);
        }
        LOGINS = new String[totalRows];

        c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM password ORDER BY pas_company ASC", null);

        while(arrayField <=2 && c.moveToPosition(added))
        {
            LOGINS[added] = c.getString(1) + "\n" + c.getString(3);
            added++;
        }

        if (totalRows == 0)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("No login records have been found.\n\n Press menu > New login to add a record")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        else
        {
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.show_login, LOGINS));

            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }

    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.d("Database Error", ex.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        myDB.close();
        c.close();
        count.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use ListActivity you get a content layout specified by the system if you don't specify one yourself. Create your own layout for the activity that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!-- Ad view goes here with layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="wrap_content" -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Set it using `setContentView` as usual. ListActivity needs a ListView with id `@android:id/list` that it can find if you're using a custom layout. The height=0, weight=1 configuration of the list will give it all remaining space in the layout after the ad's height is measured.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is now sort of working and displaying the ad. The problem is though none of the items are being shown in the listadapter. I've added a TextView in the XML you suggested above and set the list adapter to use the text view but nothing is being added. The list adapter is being set by using setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.showLogin_box, LOGINS));

Comment: You should have two layout xml files, one like the one I showed above and one for the list items. Say the one above is R.layout.list_layout and the item layout you illustrated in your question is R.layout.list_item. You would setContentView(R.layout.list_layout) and setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.showLogin, LOGINS));

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping. This solution works perfectly so thank you especially @adamp

Comment: You're quite welcome :-) ListViews can be tricky until you get the hang of how they work.

Comment: I had this same issue, and adamp's advice worked great for me.  Except the list takes up the whole screen when the ad comes in so part of the list is showing under the ad.  Advice?  I have set the layout_width, height, weights as adamp suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, you don't want the admob advert to have anything to do with the ListAdapter.

You want to add the admob advert to the bottom of you're LinearLayout, but you need to tell us why the application force closed.

Tell us that and we might be able to help you from there.

Comment: I haven't got a LinearLayout it is just setting the ListAdapter as the view and when I add the advert it just comes up with a NullPointerException the requestFreshAdd();

Comment: You must be pulling in some sort of XML file to set the content view. That or you're creating the view entirely from code (No idea why you'd do that).

Either way, you add the admob view in the root layout file (the one where you call setContentView(R.layout.foo)) or you create an admob view in code as well.

Comment: I'm not calling setContentView anywhere in the class. The only XML is the one I mentioned in my question which only has the TextView

Comment: Can you just post your entire Activity, all the code you've post isn't relevant to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GauntFAce I have added the code for the activity as you requested

Comment: so you want to place the advert in the xml file - show_login

Then do as adamp has said with regards to setting up the list view (Although I reckon you've probably already done it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `getListView()` then your xml `R.layout.myScreen` is not just a `TextView`. It should contain a `<ListView>`.

You don't need to add the Admob's `View` from the adapter. You can place it in you View below the `ListView`. Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <AdmobSomething android:id="@+id/admob"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/admob" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not actually calling R.layout.myScreen I just put that as an example that I wasn't setting a contentView like you would on a normal layout. There is no XML file being called except for the XML which has the textView for the ListAdapter